# sql/mysql subtract a set of keywords from results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `MOVIES` that has these fields: `genre` and `classification`. I am searching for all the Action movies but NOT the animated-action ones.

Each row contains all the classifications for example a row looks like:

```
Action,thriller,animated-action,movie
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM movies 
WHERE $email_filter 
concat( movies.genre,  movies.classification) like '%Action%' 
AND NOT LIKE '%Animated-Action%'
```

This is what I tried. It returns 0 results. Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: how will your resulting concat look for example in this case? please couple examples of concat.

Comment: What's $email_filter doing in there? I see no explanation of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query -

```
SELECT * FROM movies
WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET('Action', classification) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET('Animated-Action', classification);
```

Also, I'd suggest you to normalize data.

Answer (score 0):

but that's correct.
the row above "Action,thriller,animated-action,movie" shouldn't be returned because it is like  '%Animated-Action%'.

If you have a row like 'Action,thriller,action,movie' it will be returned.

Can you show an example of a row that you think it should be returned but it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

hope this one helps

```
select * from  
 (SELECT *,concat( movies.genre,  movies.classification) as s 
 FROM movies WHERE $email_filter AND
 concat( movies.genre,  movies.classification) like '%Action%') as b 
 WHERE s not like '%Animated-Action%'
```